# Where should I define helper method in Phoenix project?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Where should I define helper method in Phoenix project?

I want to define helper method like Rails.
But I am wondering where should I define helper method.

the method is used in template, view, model and controller.
I defined the methods in model like following and import in web.ex.
Is it right?
Or should I define these in views?

```
# web/models/session.ex

defmodule UserAuthenticator.Session do
  alias UserAuthenticator.User

  @doc """
    return current user logged in
  """
  def current_user(conn) do
    id = Plug.Conn.get_session(conn, :current_user)
    if id, do: UserAuthenticator.Repo.get(User, id)
  end

  @doc """
   check whether user login in
  """
  def logged_in?(conn) do
    !!current_user(conn)
  end
end
```

Comment: I used the method found here - worked out well: https://medium.com/@andreichernykh/phoenix-simple-authentication-authorization-in-step-by-step-tutorial-form-dc93ea350153

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no “you should define helpers *there*” in the first place. Elixir functions are just functions.

But importing the whole model into somewhere else does not sound as a good idea. If you need to have a bundle of functions to be available in the set of other modules, the most common approach would be to declare a helpers module as:

```
defmodule Helpers do
  defmacro __using__(_opts) do
    quote do
      def func1, do: func2()
      def func2, do: IO.puts 'yay'
    end
  end
end
```

and `use Helpers` everywhere you need these functions:

```
defmodule A do
  use Helpers

  def check, do: func1()
end
A.check #⇒ 'yay'
```

More on [`Kernel.use/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#use/2) (check *Best practices*.)

---

If, on the other hand, you just want to have helpers declared in some dedicated place and different modules are supposed to need different functions, use [`Kernel.SpecialForms.import/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#import/2) *with explicit `only` parameter* to prevent name clash:

```
defmodule Helper do
  def func1, do: IO.puts '1'
  def func2, do: IO.puts '2'
end

defmodule M1 do
  import Helper, only: [:func1]
end
```

Comment: I don't think that defining functions in a `__using__` macro would be 'the most common approach'. In the best practices section you linked it strongly advises against it.

Comment: @MikeBuhot I’d suggest you to re-read the _best practices_. It advises against `quote do: import Self`.

Comment: @mudasobwa 
Thank you for answering.

> There is no “you should define helpers there” in the first place. Elixir functions are just functions.

I understand it. It will be helpful for me.
I define module in view and import it.

Comment: @mudasobwa: > Finally, developers should also avoid defining functions inside the __using__/1 callback, unless those functions are the default implementation of a previously defined `@callback` or are functions meant to be overridden (see defoverridable/1). Even in these cases, defining functions should be seen as a “last resort”.

Comment: Elixir emphasis: "explicit is better than implicit. Clear code is better than concise code" means that macros should be used as last resort. https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/meta/macros.html

Comment: @Cyzanfar this is written for those who don’t understand what they do. As soon as you understand, you are free to break rules.